# AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Tags: python

I am trying to a reverse split of a URL generated from a text file and am getting the above error when printing that split value. I have tried making a string from the URL and splitting that, but this causes the GUI to freeze completely and not even produce an error message. My code is here:

```
a = URLS.rsplit('=', 1)
```

The code I used when attempting to resolve a string from the URL then split that is here:

```
urlstr = str(URLS)
a = urlstr.rsplit('=', 1)
print(a)
```

Can anyone tell me why I cant split the URL using the split method (the URLS were defined in a dictionary) and/or why creating a string and then splitting that is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The error suggests that `URLS` is not a string, but rather a `dict_values` object. I think that's what you get when you call the `values` method of a dictionary (in Python 3). A values view is an iterable object, so you probably want to loop over it, with something like:

```
for url in URLS:
    a = url.rsplit("=", 1)
    # do stuff with a here
```

Or if you want a list of the various `a` values, you could use a list comprehension:

```
a_lst = [url.rsplit("=", 1) for url in URLS]
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dict_values` object is a sequence. It does not have an `rsplit` method, though `str` objects do.

Really though, instead of using `rsplit`, you probably should be using [urllib.parse](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) to extract information from your URLs.

For example,

```
>>> import urllib.parse as parse
>>> url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions?x=foo&y=bar'
>>> parse.urlsplit(url)
SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='stackoverflow.com', path='/questions', query='x=foo&y=bar', fragment='')
>>> parse.urlsplit(url).query
'x=foo&y=bar'
>>> parse.parse_qs(parse.urlsplit(url).query)
{'x': ['foo'], 'y': ['bar']}
```

So, if URLS is a dict, then you can loop through the values and extract the parameter values using

```
>>> URLS = {'a': 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions?x=foo&y=bar'}
>>> for url in URLS.values():
...     print(parse.parse_qs(parse.urlsplit(url).query))
... 
{'x': ['foo'], 'y': ['bar']}
```

Unlike `rsplit`, [parse_qs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) will allow you to properly unquote percent-encoded query strings, and control the parsing of blank values.